# Oracle Enterprise Manager export real time monitoring for more databases in separate window

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am using Oracle Cloud Manager 13c.
I have many databases, but I would like to track the CPU load of only five or six important ones.

I see the Performance Hub where I can see the load and also performance when I click on goals-databases where we can see the graph of CPU load against active sessions.

As I need to click on every database to get that output, I was wondering if I can make some kind of export (like separate active html page) to have all of the databases at one place like a summary?

Thanks in advance.